# Booting into VNCViewer on a Raspberry Pi.

Tags: boot, vnc, init.d

Here's my problem. I'm new to Linux scripting and RasPi and I am beating my head against the wall on an issue. I want to use this raspi for displaying a vm using VNC. I got VNC installed. Created a .VNC file and have a command line command that launches it as I want.

`vncviewer -config /home/pi/.vnc/albmattrack.vnc`

Put that in a script and made it executable. Worked like a charm.

Now I want it to do that on login. I followed the instructions [here(debian-administration.org)](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian). I basically took that script and dropped the above line into the start section. I then put it in init.d. and did the update-rc.d like it said.

Ugh. Nothing happens when I boot. Now if I manually run the script it does not launch the viewer, I assume because of the Case statement and this not being at boot.

Additionally, I tried just creating a Cron job in webmin and that won't work with the commands in it or a command to execute a working script. Did some research and it looks like maybe Cron can't handle launching that. If I run the cron in webmin it gives me an error.

This seems easy but I'm stalling out and everything I look up regarding VNC and boot on Google is giving me results for VNCServer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. All of my problems were caused by the fact that I was trying to automate the launching of a GUI. Thanks to [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=344408#p344408) I was able to get this to work using x server and .xinitrc. Thanks to the guys over in Raspberrypi for pointing me in the right direction.